# How to send input to a C program using a shell script

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have a C program in which I use `scanf` to get user input. Now, I would like to make a .sh script that automatically test this program with pre-defined user input, but I'm not sure how I can send the input every time the program needs it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
./a.out << EOF
first line of input
second line of input
EOF
```

Comment: @ValentinRadu If you want to read more about this feature, it's called a heredoc or [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here-document).

Comment: Cool, I see that you can use any kind of "tags" not only `EOF`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but EOF is the convention, unless you think your input might have have that string in it.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to have an automated conversation with your program (i.e. want to interpret the output as well), take a look at [expect.](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm)  This is a tcl based tool for automating interactive sessions.  It might give you what you want.

Comment: Seems cool, but it's more than what I need:)